# Word occurrences and line numbers

Tags: c

I'm making a program that generates a text file that contains the occurrences of words and the line number of each occurrence of another text file.  I'm using an AVL tree struct that contains the word and a linked list struct that contains one node for each line number.  Here are the struct definitions:

```
struct llnode {
    struct llnode *next;
    int num;
};
struct node {
    char *word;
    struct llnode *head;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    int height;
};
```

I get a segmentation fault when I try to print to the text file using the below functions.

```
void listprint(struct llnode *p) {
    if(p->next == NULL) {
        printf("%d", p->num);
    } else {
        printf("%d, ", p->num);
        listprint(p->next);
    }
}
void treeprint(struct node *p) {
    if(p != NULL) {
        treeprint(p->left);
        printf("%s: ", p->word);
        listprint(p->head);
        treeprint(p->right);
    }
}
```

Specifically the problem is this line

```
if(p->next == null) {
```

gdb gives me

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000
```

Thanks for your help.

Edit:

```
void listinsert(struct llnode *p) {
struct llnode *prev = p;
while(p != NULL) {
    prev = p;
    p = p->next;
}
p = lalloc();
p->num = line;
p->next = NULL;
prev->next = p;

struct node *addtree(struct node *p, char *w) {
int cond;
if(p == NULL) {
    p = talloc();
    p->head = NULL;
    p->word = mystrdup(w);
    p->head = listinsert(p->head);
    p->left = p->right = NULL;
} else if((cond = strcmp(w, p->word)) == 0) {
    listinsert(p->head);
} else if(cond < 0) {
    p->left = addtree(p->left, w);
    if(height(p->left)-height(p->right) == 2) {
        if(strcmp(w, p->left->word) < 0) {
            p = singleleft(p);
        } else {
            p = doubleleft(p);
        }
    }
} else {
    p->right = addtree(p->right, w);
    if(height(p->right)-height(p->left) == 2) {
        if(strcmp(w, p->right->word) > 0) {
            p = singleright(p);
        } else {
            p = singleleft(p);
        }
    }
}
return p;

int getword(char *word, int lim) {
int c;
char *w = word;
while(isspace(c = getch()));
if(c == '\n') {
    line++;
}
if(c != EOF) {
    *w++ = c;
}
if(!isalpha(c)) {
    *w = '\0';
    return c;
}
for( ; --lim > 0; w++) {
    if(!isalnum(*w = getch())) {
        ungetch(*w);
        break;
    }
}
*w = '\0';
return word[0];
```

Comment: It means that you have passed `NULL` pointer as the parameter for function `listprint`. Can you show us how you are calling `listprint` and how your are populating the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `listprint`, you are not checking if `p` is null before checking if `p->next` is null.

Comment: When I change it to `if(p == NULL || p->next == NULL)` it seems to fix that error but then I get one at the `printf("%d, ", p->num)` line.  Do you have any idea about that one?

Comment: @John: When I insert into the list, it sets a value for p->num though, why is it NULL?

Comment: @Frumpy: add `if( NULL == p) return;` before if statement.it will fix your problem.

Comment: @John: Sorry to keep bothering you, but I'm having another problem.  When I go to print the list, it turns out that every node is NULL, so it just returns without doing anything.  I edited my listinsert method into the OP.

Comment: @Frumpy: debug inside `listinsert` method by calling `listprint` method.

Comment: @Frumpy: are you passing original llnode* in `listinsert()`. make sure that the references are same.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done any C, but in your listinsert, you do `p = lalloc();`. That's only valid while you're in the function.

Comment: @Frumpy: you did not chain it.

Comment: @John It seems to work fine when I call listprint after setting p->num.

Comment: @Frumpy: Look at it this way: Iin your listinsert function, if `p` is not null, but `p->next` is, how will `p->next` get updated with the value of `lalloc()` the next level down?

Comment: @geofftnz: I'm recursively calling `listinsert` on `p->next` though, so won't it `lalloc` once it hits a NULL?

Comment: @John By chain do you mean I didn't link each node?

Comment: @Frumpy: yes. you did not link it.

Comment: @John When I call `listinsert(p->next)` won't that link it because the next is NULL and so it calls `lalloc` and inserts the number?

Comment: @Frumpy: don't use recursive call. just loop it.

Comment: @John: Okay, now I loop `p = p->next` while `p != NULL` and then I do the insert, but when I do the printing it still sees them all as NULL.

Comment: @Frumpy: have you saved the last non null p->next value and link it?

Comment: @John: Okay, I think I put together a quick and dirty version of listinsert.  It's in the OP.  Still seems to see everything as NULL.

Comment: @Frumpy: save `p` in `pre` before you enter into the while loop and if statement is not necessary inside while.

Comment: @John: Okay, I updated it in the OP.  Now I get a segmentation fault at `prev->next = p`.

Comment: @Frumpy: you are right. you need to check prev != NULL before you set p.

Comment: @John: Okay, now that all works, but it still insists that the list is NULL when I go to print it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
llnode*  listinsert(struct llnode *p) {
    struct llnode *prev = p;
    if( NULL == prev ) {
            prev = lalloc();
            prev->num= line;
            prev->next = NULL;
            return prev;
    }
    while(prev->next != NULL) {
        prev = prev->next;
    }
    prev->next = lalloc();
    prev = prev->next;
    prev->num = line;
    prev->next = NULL;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: see the return type. call like `p = listinsert(p);`

Comment: @John: I'm trying to think about how I can insert the second, third, etc. nodes.  If I find a word that is new, I can say `p->head = listinsert(p->head)` (in this case `p` is referencing the node of a tree), but I don't know what to do if I want to add a line number for the second, third, etc. occurrences of a word.

Comment: @Frumpy: so you can chain it now.

Comment: @John: I've added the function for adding a new tree node, which is where I do the linked list insertions from.  What I'm having trouble with is I don't know what to put under that first `else if` to insert into the list correctly.

Comment: @John: Never mind, I got it working.  While I've got you, I'm going to add my `getword` function to the OP.  I'm just having trouble with incrementing the line count correctly.  The code for this is copied almost directly out of K&R where `getch` and `ungetch` are used to get the next character and, when we go one character past where we want, `ungetch` pushes it back to input.